# How to specify private key for ECDSA Signing Key for Xml

Tags: c#, xml, key, ecdsa, .net-4.7

I was implementing code for signing a xml document using specific private key in .net 6
using algorithm ECDSA with
curve secp256k1  my .net6
code :

```
  ECDsaCng key = new ECDsaCng();
            key.ImportECPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privatKey), out _);
SignedXml signer = new SignedXml(doc);
            signer.SigningKey = key;
            signer.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            KeyInfoX509Data keydata = new KeyInfoX509Data(signingCertificate);
            signer.KeyInfo.AddClause(keydata);
```

and it works fine with me

but the problem is I need to do the same implementation using 4.7 .net framework  and I tried this

```
            ECParameters p = new ECParameters {
                Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
                D = Convert.FromBase64String(privatKey),
                Q = new ECPoint() {
                     X= z.Skip(1).Take(32).ToArray(),
                     Y = z.Skip(33).ToArray()
                }
            };
            ECDsaCng key = (ECDsaCng)ECDsaCng.Create(p);
SignedXml signer = new SignedXml(doc);
            signer.SigningKey = key;
            signer.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            KeyInfoX509Data keydata = new KeyInfoX509Data(signingCertificate);
            signer.KeyInfo.AddClause(keydata);
```

now there is several problem I am facing

1- I cannot find secp256k1 in named curves

2- It throws errors as Q.x,Q.y,D are not with the same length

3- the certificate Iam using includes My public key

note my privateKey is stored as base64 string

So is there a way to make it work ?
Am I on the right path?

is there any to attach this keyString to a X509Cetrifcate2 object and use

```
       signer.SigningKey = X509Cetrifcate2.Privatekey;
```

instead of

```
        signer.SigningKey = key;
```

Would it work ?

Please let me Know

Comment: Try framework 4.7.2 which fixed some issues with 4.7 with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution for my problem it is mix of 2 solutions
first (Can not find the original Link Please reffer it )
it is this code snippet for importing my private key and Generating the signature (using Bouncy Castle)

```
        string pkcs8 = @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
           "+privatKey+@"
            -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
        TextReader privateKeyTextReader = new StringReader(pkcs8);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair privateKeyParams = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(privateKeyTextReader).ReadObject();
        byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc);
        ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withECDSA"); // ASN.1/DER format
        signer.Init(true, privateKeyParams.Private);
        signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
        byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
        signatureValue = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```

and this part for generating the xml digest after canonlization

Load my xml and apply canonlization and get the output as bytes:

```
        XmlDocument invoice = new XmlDocument();
        invoice.LoadXml(doc);
        XmlDsigC14NTransform t = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        t.LoadInput(invoice);
        Stream invoiceStream = (Stream)t.GetOutput(typeof(Stream));
```

and finaly getting my InvoiceDigest

```
SHA256Cng sHA256 = new SHA256Cng();
        byte[] hash = sHA256.ComputeHash(invoiceStream);
        invoiceDigestValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```